# trying to launch emulator using shell script

Tags: android, bash, shell, android-emulator

I have created an emulator on my mac machine. When I try to launch the emulator manually from avd manager, I am successful. Also, if I launch the emulator on the command line by

```
emulator -avd nexus5_api21
```

the emulator starts. But when I write a small shell script to do the same, like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
emulator -avd nexus5_api21
```

my emulator doesn't start. It complains, that it couldn't find the .ini file. But the same command works, when I do it separately by opening a terminal. I don't have to go to a specific location for running this command successfully.

I don't understand, what the difference between the command line and the shell script is.

Comment: I tried it from avd, command line and shell script. All three work equally well. Maybe it's a Mac thing, maybe there's some other condition causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in "shebang line" of your script. It should look like

```
#!/bin/bash

emulator -avd nexus5_api21
```

voila!

I would like to advice you to get familiar with shell scripting.

Comment: This is not the problem. I just edited the question to make it readable.

Comment: @Andrey Kopeyko.............I think what you have given as answer is same to what I have posted except echo command...

Comment: While I was posting my answer, your question was not edited yet and contained a shell script error. Right now - they are identical indeed ;-)